# How to replace one face with another while editing video in Blender3.4?

Tags: animation, modifiers, objects, edit-mode

One face with another while editing video in Blender, When there are more than one face in a video and one face needs to be replaced with another face for the entire video.like Faceswap or Deepswap, video is long 10min It's fight scene from movie,they jumping ,spinning and I need to track all that.Don't even know how to add image :) I'm new to this and is all complicated :) If somebody can help me step by step I will really appreciate that. And I hope that is clear now what I want to say. I'm beginner and need explanation step by step.

Comment: I don't think Blender is designed for swapping faces unless you choose the quick and comic looking style of face swapping. Otherwise you should check if there are third party add-ons that help with the task or search for alternative specialized programs including AI solutions. You could try Ebsynth.